# scipy optimize - View steps during procedure

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am using the `minimize` function from `scipy.optimize` library. 
Is there a way to print some values **during** the optimization procedure? Values like the current x, objective function value, number of iterations and number of gradient evaluations.

I know there are options to save these values and return them **after** the optimization is over. But can I see them at each step?

Comment: Yes, by defining a callback. This is trivial to do for x, but for the other two use-cases you should wrap those functions (manual counting) and probably cache the obj too. (you must decide if disp is enough for you; it probably depends a lot on the minimizer on how verbose it is)

Comment: That is it! I did not pay attention to that option on the documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `minimize` function takes an `options` dict as a keyword argument. Accepted keys for this dict inlude, `disp`, which should be set to `True` to print the progress of the minimization.

Comment: I have the `disp` option set to `True`. It only shows the output after the procedure is done, and not during the procedure.

Comment: Then I don't know what you mean by "during the procedure". This should print out information about the objective, gradient, etc, at each step of the solver. Do you want this information at each *function evaluation*?

Comment: I think you understood it correctly. It is really at each iteration, but the `disp` option does not do that. @sascha told me about the `callback` option and it gives me the value of `x` at each step. Thanks for the help!